# Rails, send params to controller action through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it safe/acceptable to send params this way to create action in the controller? Is there any potential problems?

```
<%= link_to "Acceptance", acceptances_path(acceptance: {favor_id: @favor.id, user_id: current_user.id}), method: :post %>
```

and then in controller

```
class AcceptancesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @acceptance = Acceptance.new(acceptance_params)

    if @acceptance.save
      redirect_to favors_path
    else
      render :template => 'favors/index'
    end
  end

  private

  def acceptance_params
    params.require(:acceptance).permit(:favor_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Thanks :) The thing is, Acceptance `belongs_to :user` and also `belongs_to :favor` . Is it still acceptable to pass params with link_to when there is an association? or there is a better way of setting the attributes in the controller?

Comment: you can `.merge(favor_id: @favor.id, user_id: current_user.id)` to your permited params. But I don't suggest you set it in view.

Answer (score 2):

The best (and the safest) you could do is assigning these id's in controller.

Since you have access to `@favor` and `current_user` objects, you'd be better of doing this:

```
def create
  @acceptance = Acceptance.new(acceptance_params)
  @acceptance.favor_id = @favor.id
  @acceptance.user_id = current_user.id
  # code omitted
end
```